Colon not working when used in Opensearch regex query dsl
I have a message field with value like below:
{"id":"abc123","duration":120}
I want to filter all logs with duration value greater than 200 using regex. When I use regex below, I am able to filter out logs with duration
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "message": "\"duration\""
    }
  }
}

This works perfectly, but if I add the :, somehow I don't see any logs at all. Same even if I use .
P.S.
I am also exploring using range like below but
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "message.duration": {
        "gt": 200
      }
    }
  }
}


I think it is because of this Regular expressions are applied to the terms (that is, tokens) in the field—not to the entire field. See https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/query-dsl/term/regexp/

I am new to Opensearch. What does token mean here? Also, does it mean I really cannot use : in the regex? Quite weird to me since I can use "

In your mapping, what is the field type of message?

Field type is unknown. This is because it can contain free text as well

What do you see when you request the mapping at for example GET http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_mapping

I see the type is "text"

And your range query from your example is not working right?

Yes, not working, and does not return any result. One possible reason I found online says the duration field value is not integer. Don't know if need parse it and how

If all the messages have the same format, you could update the mapping to let message have two properties, id with string and duration with type integer to use the range query. Or you can use the nested type for message and then do the range query. If you use the nested type, you would have to slightly update the query to nested.

Updating the format is not option tho. I don't have access to server. Only doing search for investigation

If you run this GET http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_analyze with this payload {"text":"{\"id\":\"abc123\",\"duration\":120}","field":"message"} it will give you the tokens for that payload. I think you will see that duration is a token and that is why your regex with a colon will not find it.

Also, the meaning of this regex "\"duration\"" is not matching the double quotes. The double quotes are used to specify that all text between them should be matched literally.

I see. Hmm, is there a way I can use range correctly instead?
